# NullPointerException when generating PDF using Docx4j

Tags: java, pdf

This is the error my app throws:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:199)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:159)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:168)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:82)
    ... 63 more
```

**Code:**

```
InputStream is = ByteSource.wrap(bytes).openStream();
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, baos, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
```

The line which throws NPE is

```
Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, baos, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Which line in particular is throwing the NPE?

Comment: @VHS This line "Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, baos, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);"

Comment: I think I have an answer for you. Please post another question so that I can post an answer. Please do not use the word "Null Pointer Exception" in your question. Otherwise people will simply close your question thinking that it is a duplicate.